# Homebrew Formula for emacs' VM (View Mail)

Tags: email, homebrew, emacs

Can anyone help with a homebrew formula to install emacs' VM ("View Mail"), located:

```
http://www.nongnu.org/viewmail/
https://code.launchpad.net/vm
```

I can get as far as a script, that should look like this:

```
bzr get lp:vm
cd vm
./configure --with-emacs=~/.homebrew/bin/emacs --prefix=~/.homebrew 
make
make install
```

This clearly depends on emacs & bzr.  It should also be updated any time emacs is and any time "bzr get" returns a new version.  I have looked at a few example formulae which include a url for wget and a sha1sum of the downloaded file, but since this script doesn't involve these, I'm having trouble knowing where to start.

Here's what I have looking at those example formulae, but as I say, I don't know what to do with the "url" and "sha1" methods:

```
require "formula"

class ViewMail < Formula
  homepage "http://www.nongnu.org/viewmail/"
  url "what do I do with this when download uses bzr get ...?"
  sha1 "ditto"

 depends_on :emacs
 depends_on :bzr

  def install
    system "bzr", "get", "lp:vm"
    system "cd", "vm"
    system "./configure", "--with-emacs=#{prefix}/bin/emacs", "--prefix=#{prefix}" 
    system "make"
    system "make", "install"
  end

end
```

Comment: I don't believe that bzr is needed. Not sure if any brew recipes use bzr, git or anything to first check for the newest version and then download. Not sure if people manually update formulas as new versions come out. Creating the formula per instructions, 'brew create URL[of the .gz]' fills in a lot of the info. I removed the requirements except for emacs, and get a different error.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
class Vm < Formula
  desc "VM is a mail reader that runs under XEmacs and GNU Emacs."
  homepage "https://launchpad.net/vm"
  url "https://launchpad.net/vm/8.2.x/8.1.93a/+download/vm-8.1.93a.tgz"
  version "8.1.93a"
  sha256 "9eab4cca6d8e4f3c5b2ab0293caecda3207b8f7e5d1e620d067898c35204235e"

  depends_on :emacs => ["23", :build]

  def install
    system "./configure", "--with-emacs=#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/bin/emacs",
            "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    system "make"
    system "make install"
 end

def caveats; <<-EOS.undent
  To use add to .emacs:
  (add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/Cellar/vm/8.1.93a/share/emacs/site-lisp/vm")
  (require 'vm-autoloads)
  EOS
end
```

Though I'm not sure how to dynamically list the necessary prefix for the load-path in the caveats.